# How to display PrimeFaces Calendar with Buddhist Era format

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I want to display BE calendar in client side , but the backing bean still AD calendar. , How to do that?

I tried to set year to +543 in backing bean

```
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(dt); 
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 543);
dt = c.getTime();
```

so it will have BE year , but they are not equals in format , as you see in the picture

[image]

first one is BE calendar that have 28 days , but AD have 29 days and BE 1st is on Wednesday ,  but AD 1st is on Friday

I saw this link , I tried to add it on my project , but what I am need to do next? 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-ui-datepicker-extension-buddhist-era/

or I can do with custom locale script at this line?

```
PrimeFaces.locales ['th'] = {
.
.
yearSuffix:'',
.
}
```

but I still don't know how to get year from the calendar component